# Transformer in flyback DC-DC converter

Tags: transformer

How can a DC supply be given to the transformer primary in a flyback DC to DC converter? In a flyback converter there is a transformer and DC supply is given to it. How?

Comment: It is switched on and off, so although it is not strictly *Alernating* current is does have the same effect.

Comment: [Wikipedia - flyback conveter](http://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F8%2F86%2FFlyback_conventions.svg%2F1280px-Flyback_conventions.svg.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFlyback_converter&h=760&w=1280&tbnid=Xe1U2TyqPP8IYM%3A&zoom=1&docid=wlD2qv6T_7001M&ei=KeUaVPbQBcSA8QXboYEg&tbm=isch&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=2563&page=1&start=0&ndsp=41&ved=0CCUQrQMwAQ) from JRE's search  - explains it well. see fig 1 and text.

Answer (score 2):

A fly-back DC/DC converter is a [SMPS or Switch Mode Power Supply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply). Basically, this is a type of power supply, based on the generation of power pulses, which are applied to a storage power element. There are many types that can be implemented on this basis.

In this case, the power pulses are applied to the primary winding of a transformer (flyback transformer). The variable current generated is transferred to the secondary of the transformer, where the rectified and filtered.

Why so complicated assembly for a power supply? Because this way of working provides better performance than a [linear regulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regulator), among other features.

**Append**: here is a basic block diagram for the system. The PV module feeds the power Switch, wich applies a pulsed DC to the fly-back transformer. In the secondary of the transformer, the pulsed DC is rectified and filtered.

[image]

If your question is: why use the DC / DC converter, instead of directly connecting the PV module? The answer is that the *PV module does not provide a regulated output*, then inserting a DC / DC converter, not only I get a very good output regulation, but also can obtain different voltage levels.

Comment: Here Flyback converter is fed from a PV module. so a dc is given to flyback transformer. If it is power pulses, then what is the meaning of DC-Dc converter?

Comment: @MinuAshiqahPK The PV module is the DC source for the DC/DC converter. The DC from the PV module is chopped by the power switch circuit of the fly-back converter, generating a pulsed power signal. I will try to add a basic schema.

Answer (score 1):

In a flyback converter, the transformer stores energy.  It can be thought of as two inductors magnetically coupled together since they are wound on a single core.

Refer to figure 1 at  [Wikipedia - Flyback Converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_converter)

When the power switch is closed, the input voltage is applied to the primary side. This causes primary current to increase, causing the magnetic flux in the core to increase. Energy is stored in the flux. In this way, energy is transferred from the input to the core. A voltage appears on the secondary; this is blocked by the diode.

When the switch is opened, and the input current is turned off, the core flux starts to decrease, inverting the polarity of the primary and secondary voltages. The diode now conducts, and current flows in the secondary to the output. The energy stored in the core is transferred to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at the schematics for a DC-DC flyback converter ([Google picture search for dc-dc flyback converter](https://www.google.de/search?q=dc%20dc%20flyback%20converter&biw=1280&bih=952&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=POMaVPv9GMvnygOo7IHQDw&sqi=2&ved=0CDwQsAQ) and you will see that the primary is fed with a pulsating voltage, not with DC.